# Angular 12 lazy loading module with Formly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-formly

I have problem with lazy loading module. Every time when I want to do it Formly thow me Error

`ERROR Error: [Formly Error] The type "input" could not be found. Please make sure that is registered through the FormlyModule declaration.`

Structure of my project with I have is:

```
Appmodule:
   PublicModule:
      AuthModule
```

and in Auth module I have

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

register like this `RouterModule.forChild(routes)`

and my PublicModule has only:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'user',
        loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)
      }
    ]),
```

And in AppModule I have only this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];
```

registered like this `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`

and I don't know why angular thow me exception when I open login link.

Thank for help in advance

Comment: If formly is a module, have you added it to the imports of `AuthModule`

Answer (score 2):

looks like you are using ngx-formly for form creation in your application, the error could be possibly because of missing declarations and imports in the module.
below are the necessary imports to be added in your LoginComponent's module file

----imports

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormlyModule } from '@ngx-formly/core'; 
import { FormlyBootstrapModule } from '@ngx-formly/bootstrap';
 // incase your are using bootstrap ui-theme
```

Also add them into your imports array in the same module file

```
imports: [   
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormlyBootstrapModule,  
    FormlyModule.forRoot(),
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

On your module imports you need to specify the types of fields that you will be using like so:

```
 import { FormlyFieldInput } from '@ngx-formly/material/input';

 imports: [
  FormlyModule.forRoot({
  types: [{ name: 'input', component: FormlyFieldInput }],
  })
 ]
```